# How to use FFImageLoading to implement animated GIF into a Splash Screen

Tags: xamarin.forms

I followed this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

to create a Splash Screen and it works very well.
I´m using FFImageLoading to display Gifs inside APP, and it works, but i don´t how to do it to play a Gif as Splash Screen...

Could you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Android, you could try to use `Refractored.GifImageView` to create GIF Splash Screen. For ios, according to Apple's policy, we can't use a gif as the app's splash screen. We could only use static images as the launch screen.

Comment: I´m sorry, i´m currently developing a Cross-Platform APP, but focusing on Android Project, and Refractored.GifImageView only works Xamarin Android...
Thanks in advance

Comment: We could try to play an animated gif image first to emulator Splash Screen. And then show the main page after the animation finished.